# htmlcxx API usage

Tags: c++, html

I am using the [htmlcxx library](http://htmlcxx.sourceforge.net/) to read an HTML file and generate the same HTML file with additional content.

I can read the file with no problem, but simply emitting the original HTML file doesn't correctly include the end tags.  That is, when I simply iterate and output the entire DOM, no closing tags are emitted.

I know that there is a `closingText()` interface for a node (see `Node.h`), but I can't seem to find a way to use it that lets me do what I need.

Here is how I'm dumping the DOM:

```
it = dom.begin();
end = dom.end();
for (; it != end; ++it)
{
    cout << it->text();
}
```

The above gives me:

```
<div>
    <li>
       <div>
(blank)
(blank)
(blank)
<div>
(blank)
```

for the following html:

```
<div>
    <li>
        <div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

Anything i can do other than changing the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is virtually no documentation provided with this library, and only a *very* small set of example code. The tree manipulation was lifted from http://tree.phi-sci.com and that site has a little more documentation, but not much in the way of additional example code.

Every example that I have seen uses the basic "depth-first" iterator, which allows you to traverse the tree using a simple for loop. This doesn't seem to be very useful, since to serialize an HTML tree, you really need to use recursion.

I hacked about until I got a recursive algorithm working. This may not be the best way to use the library, but it seems to work.

```
void walk_tree( tree<HTML::Node> const & dom )
{
    tree<HTML::Node>::iterator it = dom.begin();
    cout << it->text();
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < dom.number_of_children(it); i++ )
    {
        walk_tree( dom.child(it, i) );
    }
    cout << it->closingText();
}
```

As you can see from my code, the `text()` and `closingText()` functions bracket whatever content is contained in the sub-tree which is processed recursively.

Comment: Thanks, that will do the trick! In my original edit when I said "I can only use it for the opening tag", I meant that the Node associated with the opening tag has the api closingText(). For example for the node with <div>, I can get </div> using closingText(). But I wanted to have an actual node for </div> so that things would be in order. I've updated my question. But your algorithm will allow the proper ordering. Thanks.

Comment: The other option I was going to look into is to simply modify the htmlcxx source to add the closing node. It doesn't look too painful to do that but you saved me a good chunk of time.

Comment: Since `dom.child()` function uses linked list navigation to get to the i-th child, using it in a cycle is not effective, it is better to use a `sibling_iterator` like this: `for (tree<HTML::Node>::sibling_iterator childIt = dom.begin(it); childIt != dom.end(it); ++childIt) {  walk_tree(childIt);  }`

Comment: Also it's best not to construct a new tree on every recursive call (it will copy subtree), but instead pass the tree and iterator to current node as two separate parameters.

Comment: @dev_overflow how do you add closing node if the html page does not provide. for my case `<tr  class="test1"><td><span>test1</span></td>
<tr class="test2"><td><span>test2</span></td>
<tr class="test3"><td><span>test3</span></td>
<tr class="test4"><td><span>test4</span></td></tr>`,  the above 3 rows have not closing </tr>, then I use htmlcxx lib, the internal <span> can't be read, but the last row can be fetched, for such case how to change htmlcxx source code to add closing node if it does not exist, thanks.