# How to display tag attributes in htmlcxx c++ library?

Tags: c++, html, tree

How to display a html tree showing text and both tags and its attributes. I would be greteful for any decent manual or documentation for htmlcxx, I couldn't find any to help myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is quite similar to an other SO thread. The answer provided should help you to achieve your goal.

[htmlcxx API usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480570/htmlcxx-api-usage)

The code shown there walks through all childs of the dom tree and writes them to stdout, tags and text.